# Different amplitude in time-domain vs frequency-domain

Tags: frequency-spectrum

Reading the book Understanding Digital Signal Processing I am confused with the following picture: [image]

First figure is the input signal ($x_1(n) = \sin(2\pi f_0nt_s)$, $f_0$ frequency, $t_s$ being the sampling period) at 1Hz. Second is the input signal squared ($y_1(n) = \sin(2\pi f_0nt_s) \cdot \sin(2\pi f_0nt_s)$). Third figure is the second signal displayed in frequency domain. How can it be that the amplitude is $-0.5$ when the second figure is strictly positive and the amplitude is $1$?

Note: I am a complete beginner at this.

Comment: sure that the first is $x_1(n) = \sin(2\pi fnt)$, and not just $x_1(n)=\sin(2\pi fn)$?

Comment: It was like that in the book. $t$ is sample period.

Comment: I just dug up the book. He uses $f_0$ and $t_s$! It helps if you actually use the notation from the book, it makes sense.

Comment: So, addressing your question: I'm a bit confused. What's wrong with $Y_1(2) = -0.5$? looks right to me! time domain is an oscillation of frequency 2, amplitude 0.5, with a phase of $\pi$; i.e. $e^{j\pi}=-1$.

Comment: The amplitude of the signal in time domain is $1$, how is it then $-0.5$ in frequency domain? I thought they should be the same.

Comment: a) no, the amplitude is 0.5 in time domain. Look closely! b) no, they don't need to be the same – the energy must be the same (or at least proportional, depending on your definition of the Fourier transform) in time and frequency domain, but that's it.

Comment: I am curious to know who is the author of this book. Also HINT : $sin^2(\theta) = 0.5 (1-cos(2\theta)$

Comment: @jithin Rick Lyons, one of the big books about digital signal processing! He's also a user here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh that's great! I follow him on dsprelated.com too. Time to read his new blog entry in these 'lockdown' times!

Comment: @jithin check out his [user profile](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/15391/richard-lyons).

Comment: @MarcusMüller looking closely I see that amplitude in time domain is $1$. :) Can you explain please I am very new to this.

Comment: So, in your non-squared signal, what's the amplitude? What's the difference between the lowest and the highest point? In your squared signal, what's the difference between the lowest and the highest point? What is hence the amplitude?

Comment: I thought amplitude was simply the maximum point from the x-axis. What is the formula for amplitude then?

Comment: And I also thought that the amplitude cant be negative.

Answer (score 1):

> How can it be that the amplitude is −0.5

Primarily sloppy notation in the book.

The frequency domain representation of a signal uses complex numbers, i.e. you would need two real numbers to describe it. Either Amplitude and Phase or Real and Imaginary Part. The correct way to describe this would

1. Amplitude is $0.5$ and the phase is $\pi$, or
2. Real part is $-0.5$ and the Imaginary part is $0$

The whole notion of negative/positive doesn't make sense for a complex number, so you can't think about this that way.

Comment: Well I am just beginning and even the book has just started so without knowing anything else I am only analysing the graphs and I want to know how to interpret the amplitude of the second graph. Obbiously the highest point is at an amplitude of $1$ so I want to know how to see this $-0.5$.

Comment: This is not a great graph and I wouldn't try to read too much into it. You can interpret this as the "real part of the Fourier Transform" but it should show value of 1 at $0Hz$ and -0.5 at $2Hz$ AND $-2Hz$. Unless you are far along to understand why it should be this way, you'll have a hard time interpreting this